# Ошибка при настройке отладки драйверов в VirtualBox

Tags: c++, visual-studio, virtualbox, драйвер

Пытался настроить VirtualBox для тестирования драйвера по этому [гайду](https://habrahabr.ru/post/130213/) и сразу же вылетел с ошибкой в самом начале:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну там еще сложность, что все гайды уже старые, данный на xp а я 10 запускаю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хоть что-то решил, жаль никто не помог. Чтобы избежать ошибки надо снять галочку с "Подключиться к существующему каналу/сокету"

Comment: Самоответ тоже ответ.